# How does c++ compiler infer template parameters when only some provided

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-inference

I have this class template:

```
template<class Q, class V>
bool EQ(const Q& q, V v) { 
    return q.Eq(v); 
}
```

and this class:

```
struct TEq01 { 
    char n1;                
    TEq01(const void* p) : n1(*(char*)p)     { }    
    bool Eq(char n) const                { return n1 == n; }
};
```

Say I use it like this - only specifying the first template parameter

```
char *sz = "some string";
bool f = EQ<TEq01>(sz, '1');
```

How does the compiler know that TEq01 is **class Q** instead of **class V**?  I'm using visual studio 2013.

Comment: Couldn't you come up with any better identifiers? At least for this example?

Comment: which identifiers?  There are a lot!

Comment: `TEq01`, or `EQ`. Common metasyntactic names are `foo`, `bar` or `foobar`. The example code also includes many redundant lines, e.g. those defining members like `Eq` that are irrelevant to the question itself.

Comment: ok ill clean it up.  I took it out of my real live code and trimmed out a bunch of stuff, but not enough as you point out.  One sec...

Comment: Thanks, that makes questions more enjoyable to read.

Comment: i had to leave in more than would be required to just discuss the order of template parameters being maintained, but some answers already refer to the code.  I left the names.  Also, I left the bit where the compiler creates a temp TEq01 from sz, since when I first was asking the question, I thought possibly that might have had something to do with it.

Comment: The question is fine, there's no need to call everything foo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was just wondering how the compiler knows that TEq01 is class Q instead of class V? I'm using visual studio 2013.

The **first template argument** you provide is **the first template parameter**.

The order of template parameters is maintained.

Since you wrote:

```
template<class Q, class V>
bool EQ...
```

calling `EQ<TEq01>` means "`Q` is `TEq01` and `V` was not supplied, so it must be deduced."

Comment: you might add you can leave parameters blank, so EQ<,char> is a way to supply V and leave Q to be deduced.

Comment: @johnnycrash I'm pretty sure that is gramatically ill-formed.

Comment: My grammer could be bad!  EQ<,char> compiled though!

Comment: @johnnycrash Which compiler? If it compiles it's either a bug or a non-standard extension.

Answer (score 2):

That is a templated function. Function templates get their argument types from whatever they are passed. Being able to specify types in the arrows is an optional thing that you don't need to use, unless you are trying to force the use of a particular type.

When you do specify types in the arrows, the compiler goes in order, 1, 2, 3. Any types that you don't explicitly set take types from the function arguments.

Comment: The question is how does the compiler know I meant EQ<TEq01, char> when I only provided EQ<TEq01>  it could have assumed I meant EQ<char,TEq01> could it not?

Comment: Nope, because the `EQ` function takes Q first then V. It infers that since "sz" is of type TEq01, it must be that, and since the second arg is of type char, it must be that.

Comment: Are you asking how the compiler does that (probably too broad) or what the language specs says about this behaviour?

Comment: It's positional. First is first, second is second, and so on.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Wow, i just did an experiment.  I was able to call EQ<,char> and EQ<TEq01,>  Looks like you can specify any subset of the template parameters that way.

Comment: Dang, I gave the answer to someone else just a few minutes ago.